# gulp-sourcemaps, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

**Background:** I am trying to setup source mapping with my Gulp Scripts task. I believe the mapping is working ( see below that the 'hello world' console.log is referencing `main.js:10`, rather than `all.min.js`), but I am receiving a console error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

---

**The Question:** Why is this happening, and is it going to cause a problem to preclude me from fully utilizing the capabilities of js source mapping?

---

**References:**

The Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the console]

gulpfile.js:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    ignore = require('gulp-ignore');

    var paths = require('./gulp/paths.js');

//default task. 1.jshint 2.watch 3.log
gulp.task('default',['scripts','styles','watch'],function(){
    return gutil.log(gutil.colors.bold.yellow('Gulp is running!'));
});

//Styles task
gulp.task('styles',function(){
    gulp.src('styles/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())

        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true, sourceComments: 'map', sourceMap: 'sass'}).on('error', gutil.log))

        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) //Output sourcemap alongside style.css
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.')) //Output Destination is relative to gulpfile.js

        .pipe(livereload());

});

//watch task
gulp.task('watch',function(){

    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch(['js/**/*.js','!js/dist/*'],['scripts'])
    gulp.watch('styles/sass/**/*.scss',['styles']);
});

//jshint task against all custom js
gulp.task('jshint', function(){
        return gulp.src(paths.customJs)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));

});

//scripts task
gulp.task('scripts',function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.groupAll)

        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps:true}))

        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/dist'))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(uglify()).on('error', gutil.log)

        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))

        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/dist'))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Scripts task complete' }));

});
```

Project Directory Tree:

```
.
├── gulp
│   └── paths.js
├── js
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── all.js
│   │   ├── all.min.js
│   │   └── all.min.js.map
│   └── lib
│       ├── vendor
│       │   └── jquery-2.1.4.js
│       ├── 2.js
│       └── main.js
├── styles
│   └── sass
│       ├── theme
│       │   └── _colors.scss
│       └── master.scss
├── .gitignore
├── .jshintignore
├── .jshintrc
├── LICENSE.md
├── README.md
├── footer.php
├── gulpfile.js
├── header.php
├── index.php
├── layout-description.txt
├── package.json
├── sidebar.php
├── style.css
└── style.css.map
```

all.min.js.map: http://pastebin.com/wck38eHJ

---

**Note:** Yes I know JQuery offers a map file, but I wish to do it this way for various reasons.

Comment: Have a similar issue. Did you manage to solve this? Thanks

Comment: @Mantisimo No. I cannot get the console error to go away, but it appears as though the console error itself doesn't block me from using source maps.

Answer (score 3):

A sourcemap is a json object. You should load them properly; although Chrome knows it is a sourcemap and will treat it as such you ought to make sure you explicity define its type as application/json to ensure browser compatibility.

```
<script type="application/json" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

> ## [According to Google Developers platform](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-preprocessors?hl=en)
>
> Verify web server can serve Source Maps
>   Some web servers, like Google App Engine for example, require explicit configuration for each file type served. In this case, your Source Maps should be served with a MIME type of application/json, but Chrome will actually accept any content-type, for example application/octet-stream.